# How to Parse YAML with arbitrary keys

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to read in a YAML file similar to how I've done in Python. But I can't figure out how to use arbitrary keys.
I have the following YAML that I would like to read:

```
apple:
  name: item1
banana:
  name: item2
```

I know how to read in the file, but only using empty interfaces. I'd like to read it in as a map to my Item type.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Item struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name"`
}

func main() {
    input := `
  apple:
    name: item1
  banana:
    name: item2`

    m := make(map[interface{}]interface{})

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v \n", m)
}
```

What I'm getting in Stdout:

```
map[apple:map[name:item1] banana:map[name:item2]]
```

What I would like to see is:

```
map[apple:{item1} banana:{item2}]
```

How can I read my YAML file into a map of Item(s)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For unmarshaling to work the way you want, you should provide the instruction. In your case if you do not want to name to be in a map provide a struct to unmarshal.

so `m := make(map[interface{}]interface{})` should change to `m := make(map[string]Item)`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Item struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name"`
}

func main() {
    input := `
  apple:
    name: item1
  banana:
    name: item2`

    m := make(map[string]Item)

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v \n", m)
}
```

Output: `map[apple:{item1} banana:{item2}]`

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly!

Comment: Hi there, thanks for providing this solution. It's worth noting for future readers that this seems to fail if you are using tabs in your code editor, not spaces. My editor threw back the error "yaml: line [n]: found character that cannot start any token". Once I realised this and converted tabs to spaces, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `m := make(map[string]Item)`.